# Resuming from Suspend causes computer to shutdown under Linux Mint

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, drivers, suspend

I've got a fresh install of Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon on a Sony Vaio VGN-NW270F. I haven't changed any default options. It's running the latest kernel and all updates are installed. I also installed the Intel Microcode driver at the recommendation of the Driver Manager.

Whenever I suspend the machine, either by closing the lid, or using the power menu (either by pressing the power button or using the power button in Menu), the machine suspends correctly (it enters low power mode almost immediately, no formal shutdown). However, when I try to resume from suspend, by opening the lid and pressing any key, I get a boot logo followed by GRUB. As far as I can tell, it doesn't actually reboot the machine until I try to actually resume it. The suspension is working fine, the issue occurs at the resume.

I found a few older threads on some forums that mention changing /etc/acpi/events/powerbtn to resemble /etc/acpi/events/sleepbtn, however that second file no longer exists in Linux Mint, nor does /etc/acpi/sleep.sh.

Anyone know what's causing this issue, or how to resolve it? I put Linux on this machine to speed it up, but if it has to be rebooted every time it resumes from sleep, that kind of defeats the point.

Let me know if there's any more info I can provide. It's an older machine, but Windows 10 runs just fine (albeit slowly) on it, so I don't think it has any hardware issues.

Answer (score -1):

I have a very similar problem on my Vaio. This page helped:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1556934

Summary:

1. Open /etc/default/grub with your favorite editor.
2. change GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" to: 
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_sleep=nonvs"
3. sudo update-grub
4. reboot and changes should take effect.